# Working with Hours & Minutes in Python & openpyxl - Excel Formatting vs Strings & Ints

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Hoping someone with some openpyxl or general Excel experience might be able to help.
I'm working on a project to record flying hours, and produce an Excel spreadsheet of flights completed in a month.

So far, I've used PySimpleGUI to create a nice front end, and got it working so it stores each flight's details as a dictionary, where the keys are terms like the names of the crew, the aircraft registration and so on.  Each flight is separately stored in a dictionary for the current month.

To make sure the hours flown make sense, I've used number spinners so they can't get nonsense inputs. Each type of flying hour is recorded as 2 keys, one for hours and one for minutes. So the dictionary has a section with parts like:

```
'-firstPilotHours-': 1,
'-firstPilotMins-': 30,
'-captainHours-': 1,
'-captainMins-': 30,
```

.. and so on.
I've managed to get these put into Excel by converting them to strings and the concatenating them with a colon in the middle:

```
ws1.cell(row=sortieIdent, column=9).value = str(currentMonth[sortie]["-captainHours-"]) + ":" + str(currentMonth[sortie]["-captainMins"])
```

... so it appears as "1:30" in Excel, which is the way I used to input the data when I ran a manual Excel file for this purpose.

The cell's number format is set as "[h]:mm" to allow me to perform calculations on the values as hours and minutes, so there can be a monthly total shown and so on.

However, this is the point where I'm stuck. I think because I'm converting them to strings, even though they look like "1:30" in Excel, they're being handled in Excel like a string and not an integer. It's not possible to perform any calculations with them.  If I overtype them in Excel with "1:30," then they move to the right hand side of the column and start behaving like numbers.

I can't think of any way to get these into Excel in a manner where I can carry out calculations on them. Can anyone help?

I've thought about having separate columns for the hours and minutes, but I can't figure out how to work calculations in that manner either. I also thought about just displaying them as strings as it works now, but doing the calculations in Python; but I can't figure out how to do proper "hours & minutes" calculations within Python.

Comment: As python is object oriented a better approach is to work with [`time` objects](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/datetime.html#time-objects) and not with integers represeting time. That is if you need actual times, dates and such. If all you need is to count the time flown just use two columns for minutes and hours flown. Using `time` format in excel shows **time of day** which isn't the same.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this gives you some insight into Excel's date/time processing.

For a given decimal number that represents date/time...
The **left side** of the decimal represents the days since 1/0/1900.
The **right side** of a decimal number represents time.

Practical Example:

The date time I am writing this post is: 24 May 2020 @ 8:02pm

Excel's underlying value is: 43975.8347222222

43975 days since 1/0/1900 = 24 May 2020

.8347222222  =  Decimal portion of 24 hours

Having that foundation down (let me know if it isn't clear).
Now we can tackle your example.

To express 1:30 into Excel's world.
We would need to turn 1 hour and 30 minutes into a decimal day

Your 1:30 = .0625 in Excel

To show .0625, you can Format the cell as "hh:mm" or whatever you want using the custom format.

Custom Format = Display value to the user
.0625 = Underlying value Excel uses to calculate

Hope this nudges you further down the road.

Comment: Thank you; working with Excel's own way of handling time was the solution I needed!  I think I'm almost at the right stage, and then I'll post my successful code.